# Output concatenation of file contents and custom text into a new file

Tags: bash, files, cat

Sorry for a noob question but, well, I *am* a noob, so...

Given two files, say `file1` with content, say, `text1` and `file2` with content `text2`, I want to create a new file `file3` with content `text1newtextinbetweentext2`. I would expect some command like

```
cat file1 (dontknowwhat "newtextinbetween") file2 > file3
```

Is there some `dontknowwhat` that would do what I want? If not, what is the optimal way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use process substitution:

```
cat file1 <(echo "newtextinbetween") file2 > file3
```

Edit: If you don't what `echo` to add a line break use `echo -n` instead.

Comment: Wow this looks even sleeker! But how about avoiding newline between `newtextinbetween` and the contents of `file2`?

Comment: Fantastic!  Had to behave ungraciously and move my acceptance from the previous answer to this one. Essentially because what I asked there is very easy to do here, just do `cat file1 <(echo -n $WHATEVER) file2 > file3`

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე nothing ungracious about it at all! You should always accept the answer you personally find most useful. Just note that a safer/more portable way would be `cat file1 <(printf '%s' "newtextinbetween") file2 > file3` since not all `echo` implementations understand `-n` (see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)).

Comment: @terdon Thanks! Good to know. In my case `-n` worked, I just checked it, so...

Answer (score 7):

Here are two ways:

1. Group the commands

   ```
    $ { cat file1; echo "newtextinbetween"; cat file2; } > file3
    $ cat file3
    text1
    newtextinbetween
    text2
   ```
2. Use a subshell

   ```
    $ ( cat file1; echo "newtextinbetween"; cat file2 ) > file3
    $ cat file3
    text1
    newtextinbetween
    text2
   ```
3. Use command substitution

   ```
    $ printf '%s\nnewtextinbetween\n%s\n' "$(cat file1)" "$(cat file2)" > file3
    $ cat file3
    text1
    newtextinbetween
    text2
   ```

   If you don't want the newlines between each block, you can do:

   ```
    $ printf '%snewtextinbetween%s\n' "$(cat file1)" "$(cat file2)" > file3
    $ cat file3
    text1newtextinbetweentext2
   ```

Comment: ... or (bash/zsh/ksh) even `printf '%snewtextinbetween%s\n' "$(<file1)" "$(<file2)"` if you're not a cat lover

Comment: Excellent, thanks! The last version is precisely what I want. Just one detail: say, this `newtextinbetween` was the value of some variable `WHATTOINSERT`; would something like `printf '%s($WHATTOINSERT)%s\n'...` work then?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე no, variables aren't expanded inside single quotes, just add another `%s` like this: `printf '%s%s%s\n' "$(cat file1)" "$WHATTOINSERT" "$(cat file2)" > file3`

Comment: Thank you! Very nice.

Comment: Could use `{` to group instead of `(`.

Comment: @rowboat I could and I should, there's no need for a subshell. Thanks!